# Subscribing from JavaScript to RabbitMQ to receive Push Messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, using

I have a requirement of subscribing to a channel from the JavaScript (running on a browser window) to the RabbitMQ channel, so that the messages published by RabbitMQ to that channel can be received.

I would like to how I can do this without using any JS Library - like Node.js or any other.

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.3, Erlang 17.0.

Comment: NodeJS can totally handle RabbitMQ messages and forward them to a web browser. The node module you should use is called AMQP

Comment: Thanks. I saw too many sites which already talks about Node JS. But I was wondering why couldn't we do it without any library? I mean, using plain old JavaScript - At least for understanding purposes.

Comment: Wait, you know that NodeJS is server side ? I you want you can do plain-Javascript on your browser side, but to do Javascript server side to fetch MQTT packets you will defintly have to use a technology like NodeJS. If you only need to retrieve directly the messages client-side (what I would not advise you), I'm not so sure it can be done easily...

Comment: I enabled rabbitmq_web_stomp and tried to connect using a WebSocket like "ws://127.0.0.1:5762/ws" - but getting error as: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5672/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET(anonymous function) @ RabbitMQTester.html:12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to how I can do this without using any JS Library

you can't.

RabbitMQ requires a library - either you write it yourself (which I don't recommend) or use an existing library.

But you shouldn't be connecting from your browser, anyways. The browser should talk to the web server, and the web server should connect to RabbitMQ.

Use websockets or server-side events to communicate from the web server to the browser.

Comment: OK. Please consider this: The front-end of the application that runs on the browser needs data, which may have longer processing time. So, it establishes a subscription to RabbitMQ queue (Using WebSocket) and posts the request to the WebServer that it need some data and when ever it is ready, push it to the queue. Are you suggesting that this is a wrong approach? In that case, what else can I try out?

Comment: It's not a wrong approach, but as far as I could understand things from your previous messages, you wanted to access directly to the RabbitMQ messages from your browser, via client-side Javascript. That's what, @Derick Bailey and I, didn't recommended you to do. But of course, using WebSockets to poll for messages on a Web Server that talk with RabbitMQ is a good solution :)

Comment: Yes, my interpretation was not correct. Thanks to you Derick and Alex. I could connect to RabbitMQ using WebSocket and SUBSCRIBE to the queue that I am interested to listen to. It works fine.